# RMarkdown and Hugo Site Generator

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio, r-markdown, hugo

I'm using Hugo Site Generator and I have installed it using Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 - VirtualBox as a VM. Hosted by W10).

I don't know exactly how can I use files .Rmd in the Blog's content without using blogdown package (I decided not using the RStudio because of a lot of bugs and lack of performance).

Anyone could help me how can I setting up this issue without using RStudio and blogdown package?

Obs.: I'm sorry about that Yihui Xie, but even re-installed n times RStudio, I decided to use a Linux Plataform directly...

Best!

Answer (score 0):

I expect your Hugo site is working fine on your Linux platform. And you are looking for a suitable IDE to work with your files in Hugo. We are using an IDE which is suitable for almost all kind of developments

You can download it from here [Download Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)

If you are developing with your own local machine you can configure a workspace in your IDE like this 
[image]

Otherwise, you can use extensions like [FTP SIMPLE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple) or using GitHub and netlify to

In Visual studio Code, you will get Hugo extensions to build your Hugo site like the following

1. [Hugofy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akmittal.hugofy)
2. [Hugo Helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rusnasonov.vscode-hugo)

Please try out this method

Comment: Tks! I will use this steps and see if it works fine! Best